# Ubuntu forward ports, default state, forwarding not working?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables

im running ubuntu 12.04.4 server. I been googling for answers, but could not find any..
I would like access a few web-gui's on my server.
I have forwarder the ports in my router. Its working when I run the same programs on a windows server, but when I went over to linux it does not work when im not on LAN.

I have not configured Iptables at all.. As far as i know Iptables is accepting all requests by default?

Anyway, if i need to configure iptables this is the port.
Looks like on lan: server-lan-ip:9090 and i would reach the web-gui.
When i used windows server is could simply reach the web-gui form external locations on: "my-exsternal-ip:9090"

Any suggestions to what i should do?
iptables -L -n shows that everything is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For begining you look on witch port your web application work under ubuntu

```
netstat -a
```

Is averting ok you will see:

```
tcp        0      0 *:9090                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

This mean that you server listen for incoming connection on this port.
Default port for https is 443. Maybe you server listen on that port.

If is iptables without rules is disabled.
To catch traffic on 9090 and redirect to 443 add before filter section in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9090 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443
COMMIT
```

Then restart ufw.